# Integração Identity x Azure AD x ADFS do cliente

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, active-directory, owin

Possuo uma aplicação com autenticação via banco de dados usando OWIN e Identity. Um cliente solicitou single sign on com o ADFS on premisse. Fiz diretamente pelo OWIN, porém o cliente solicita uma url de federação (com metadados), o que eu não possuo. Para contornar, penso em autenticar com o Azure AD com o menor esforço possível (pensei em utilizar a biblioteca ldap e só verificar se o usuário existe) e no Azure AD configurar o SSO.

Esse cenário é válido?

Answer (score 0):

[IdentityServer](https://github.com/identityserver) será sua melhor saída. Ele irá te fornecer todos os meios de credenciamento possíveis e necessários.

Ele suporta várias maneiras de autenticação:

- Windows integrated authentication: se tiver rodando em um Windows Server com IIS e dentro de um domínio AD.
- Username/password: via LDAP e federação (com OpenID Connect/ADFS or domínio junto ao IdentityServer)

E com ele vc criar SSO (Single Sign On) para quantas aplicações precisar, usando credenciamento nivel usuário ou nivel *app client*.